# Azure: BadRequest - Pending managed certificate failed (The domain or certificate request triggered a risky domain check)

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service, certificate

I tried to generate an Azure App Service Managed Certificate for a new Azure App Service that I set up.

When I run the command to generate the Azure App Service Managed Certificate:

```
az webapp config ssl create --resource-group MyResourceGroup --name MyAppService --hostname www.mywebsite.com
```

I get the error below:

> Bad Request({"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Pending managed certificate failed: Certificate creation was rejected by CA for canonical name auth.uat.8451.audigent.com: The domain or certificate request triggered a risky domain check. Please contact Azure for assistance for this request. If retrying does not help, please contact support for assistance. Refer to the documentations for more info: [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2158627."](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2158627.%22)

I have tried twice to re-run the certification generation command, the error still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's how I fixed it**:

Just take a **break of about 1 to 2 minutes** and retry the Azure App Service Managed Certificate command:

```
az webapp config ssl create --resource-group MyResourceGroup --name MyAppService --hostname www.mywebsite.com
```

It should work fine now.

If it still persists though, then contact Azure support for assistance. Refer to the documentations for more info: [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2158627."](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2158627.%22)

Answer (score 1):

Glad to know that the issue is resolved. Thanks for the update, @Promise Preston

The **App Service Managed certificate** is a free certificate is issued by DigiCert. For some domains, you must explicitly allow DigiCert as a certificate issuer by creating a **CAA domain record** with the value: `0 issue digicert.com.`. I have seen cases where by completing the above the error goes away.

For more details on App Service Managed certificate, please see these docs:
[Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate#prerequisites) and [Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate#create-a-free-managed-certificate)